# Neural networks when there are multiple correct answers

Tags: neural-networks

How could I train a potential neural network if there are multiple possible outputs?

For a simple example, if I'm trying to make a neural network that can find a valid solution to a quadratic equation, there could be 0, 1, or 2 correct answers. I want the network to be able to output all of the correct answers. Is this possible? If so, what techniques exist?

Comment: do you assume that you have all correct answers in your data for each record or just some of them?

Comment: For now I was thinking of applying this to function approximation so I can generate my data set dynamically.

Comment: One thing you could do ofcourse is having multiple neurons in the output layer, if there are two answers then all other neurons should output a 'n/a' number, e.g. 0. Oh, and maybe this would help http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/96225/neural-network-what-if-there-are-multiple-right-answers-for-a-given-set-of-inpu

Comment: Neural networks are capable of handling multiple outputs. You may just need to pivot your training/testing data in a way where there are multiple outputs, say, instead of `1` output column there should be `p` output columns.

Comment: What if I have an unknown, unbounded number of potential answers?

Comment: Are you familiar with RNN, LSTM, and related models?

Comment: @Sycorax  the candidate duplicate does not explicitly specify that the number of correct outputs varies (maybe still a duplicate)