# Neural Network and H2O.ai: inputs that have multiple right answers (questions about a previously answered question)

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, multi-class, h2o

I have two questions related to [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/96225/neural-network-what-if-there-are-multiple-right-answers-for-a-given-set-of-inpu) previously answered question.

1. Can someone explain how the NN's backproagation algorithm would not be able to function properly when inputs have multiple right answers?
2. I have a similar problem where in a data set, there are times when the inputs result in a certain output, and other times when the inputs result in a completely different (but equally valid) output. I am trying to use H2O.ai to train a model on this data, but am new to the platform. Does anyone know how this can be done?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your question 1, I read the linked-to answer as it will work.
And regarding question 2, one of the nice things about H2O is how easy it will be to try it out, but I believe it should just work. (I suspect training in batches might cause problems, but because H2O updates weights after every training sample, i.e. batch size of 1, I think it will be okay.)

E.g. if you have three possible outputs, A, B and C, and two inputs, and if you have a couple of training rows that look like this:

```
blue,green,A
blue,green,C
```

With a bit of luck, when you give your trained network the inputs of "blue" and "green" it will give a probability of 0.5 for A, 0.0 for B, and 0.5 for C. A bit of noise might mean C is 0.501, and A is 0.498, and B is 0.001, in which case it would predict C consistently. But, as I understood the question, that is fine?

Comment: What you say might work IF the output of the NN is a number (between 0 and 1) which can be interpreted as a probability !

Comment: @aginensky At least in H2O, that is what the outputs are for a binomial or multinomial classification: numbers between 0.0 and 1.0, that will total to 1.0. And if you train for logloss (the default) it will be trying to optimize the accuracy of those probabilities.

Comment: Of course, but that is what I was saying.  Out of the box, there is no reason for a NN to return a probability, but it can be given input parameters so that it will return a probability.

Comment: I also think that, while the OP framed this as a question about h20, the question really has nothing to do with h20 and everything to do with how a trained net will react when it has ambiguous data.  I posted a comment on the linked question.  I want to give the 'original answerer' time to respond and then I will, depending on what he says, add more.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and H2O discussion, this is pretty much what I was looking for and gives me some things to think about when using H2O.